# JAVA Need help for OOP

Tags: java, oop

I need to create an object oriented C-F converter program. I need to have 2 methods for converted c to f and f to c. The method should have a return type and one parameter. This is what I have and I'm getting a bunch of errors when compiling. Can anybody help me find out what I'm doing wrong? Would be greatly appreciated :).

```
import java.io.*;

class Celsius {

    private int value, convertedValue;

    int setValue(int c) {
        value = c;
        convertedValue = (int) ((9.0 / 5.0) * value + 32);
    }

    int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    int getConvertedValue() {
        return convertedValue;
    }
}

class Fahrenheit {

    private int value, convertedValue;

    int setValue(int f) {
        value = f;
        convertedValue = (int) ((9.0 / 5.0) * value - 32);
    }

    int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    int getConvertedValue() {
        return convertedValue;
    }
}

class FCconvert {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(inStream);
        String inData, choice1, choice2;
        int input, c, f;
        choice1 = "cel";
        choice2 = "fah";

        System.out.println("Please choose Celsius or Fahrenheit (c for celcius and f for fahrenheit)");
        inData = stdin.readLine();

        if (/*choice1 equals inData*/) {
            System.out.println("Enter a value.");
            inData = stdin.readLine();
            c = Integer.parseInt(inData);
            Celsius cel = new Celsius();
            cel.setValue(c);
            System.out.println("The converted value is: " + cel.getConvertedValue());
        }

        if (/*choice2 equals inData*/) {
            System.out.println("Enter a value.");
            inData = stdin.readLine();
            f = Integer.parseInt(inData);
            Fahrenheit fah = new Fahrenheit();
            fah.setvalue(f);
            System.out.println("The converted value is: " + fah.getConvertedValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? This does not compile for many reasons, mostly variables being used without being declared, and methods that do not return what they declare.

Comment: 'c' == inData <= compare a char with a string too.

Comment: As @MarcoAcierno stated even after getting it to compile there are fundamental problems with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (inData.equals("c"))
{
    System.out.println("Enter a value.");
    inData = stdin.readLine ( );
    c = Integer.parseInt (inData);
    Celsius cel = new Celsius();
    cel.setValue(c);
    System.out.println("The converted value is: " + c.getConvertedValue());
}
```

You need to actually create an object of `Celsius` class before using the methods. Do similarly for `fahrenheit` class. Having said that, please reconsider your class design.

Also notice change in the way strings are compared.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed a couple of stuff after seeing your answer.
But I'm now getting 2 error, a missing return statement and a cannot resolve symbol error. I'll post my code in the original post, would appreciate it if you could take a look at it :)

Comment: Use `equals` not `==` for string comparison in your `if` clause. Logic for both C-->F and F-->C are same.Change that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! really appreciate it! However I'm still getting two errors, FCconvert.java:59: ')' expected and FCconvert.java:78: illegal start of expression. I edited my main post again if you could help :)

Comment: See [this](https://ideone.com/csQIuM). Notice the use of `equals`. And you had spelling mistake!! used small'v' instead of 'V' at `fah.setValue`.

Answer (score 0):

in the if statement add creation of Celsius object as below:

```
if ('c' == inData)
{
System.out.println("Enter a value.");
inData = stdin.readLine ( );
c = Integer.parseInt (inData);
Celsius cel = new Celsius();
cel.setValue(c);
System.out.println("The converted value is: " + cel.getConvertedValue());
}
```

same for the Fahrenheit.

```
if ('f' == inData)
{
System.out.println("Enter a value.");
inData = stdin.readLine ( );
f = Integer.parseInt (inData);
Fahrenheit fahr = new Fahrenheit();
fahr.setvalue(f);
System.out.println("The converted value is: " + fahr.getConvertedValue());
}
```